# Pyspark regular expression

Tags: regex, pyspark

I have the following dataframe

```
  df = spark.createDataFrame([['<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\
  <ns1:entities>\
    <ns1:entity ns1:type="PARENT">\
      <ns1:attribute ns1:name="PARENT_ID">12345</ns1:attribute>\
        <ns1:entity ns1:instance="207" ns1:type="CHILD" ns1:id="P1">\
          <ns1:attribute ns1:name="CHILD_ID">2071</ns1:attribute>\
          <ns1:attribute ns1:name="QUESTION">One</ns1:attribute>\
          <ns1:attribute ns1:name="QUESTION1981"/>\
          <ns1:attribute ns1:name="ANS1981"/>\
          <ns1:attribute ns1:name="TEST"/>\
          <ns1:link ns1:name="QUESTION1981"/>\
        </ns1:entity>\
    </ns1:entity>\
  </ns1:entities>']], ['visitors'])
```

My Goal is to replace all ns1:attributes which are empty tags with null value

```
i.e. I want to search and replace like this
search <ns1:attribute ns1:name="QUESTION1981"/> and replace with
<ns1:attribute ns1:name="QUESTION1981">null</ns1:attribute>
```

So I am looking for a generic solution ,where it will only search within ns1:attribute and replace
i.e my outcome should be

```
<ns1:attribute ns1:name="QUESTION1981">null</ns1:attribute>
<ns1:attribute ns1:name="ANS1981">null</ns1:attribute>
<ns1:attribute ns1:name="TEST">null</ns1:attribute>
```

Is there a generic way to do itc,so far I have tried below

```
df=df.withColumn('visitors',regexp_replace('visitors','<ns1:attribute\s*\w+\d+:\w+="\w+"\s*/>','<ns1:attribute>null</ns1:attribute>'))
display(df)
```

Search part working properly,but I am struggling with replace

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it by using

```
spark.sql('SET spark.sql.parser.escapedStringLiterals=true').show()
df=df.withColumn('visitors',regexp_replace('visitors','(<ns1:attribute\s*\w+\d+:\w+=\"\w+\"\s*)(/>)','$1>null</ns1:attribute>'))
```

Below link help me got there
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/data-wrangling-in-pyspark-with-regex-ecda9b8f6256